# iOS-Swift 3-SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I updated my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I found the error of SDWebImage.

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: URL(string: book.picURL), options: .lowPriority, progress: { (min:Int, max:Int) -> Void in

            }) { (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool, url:NSURL!) -> Void in
                if image != nil && finished
                {

                    let obj = cell.keepUrl
                    if obj != nil && url != nil && obj == url
                    {
                        cell.picURL.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
```

The definition of `SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock` is the following

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock)(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL);
```

The error message is

> "Cannot convert value of type '(UIImage!, NSError!, SDImageCacheType, Bool, NSURL!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock!'"

Can anyone help me how to solve this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for the completion block is this:

```
typealias PrefetchingDone = (UIImage?, Error?, SDImageCacheType, Bool, URL?) -> Void
```

You need to make the **following changes**:

1. Change `NSError` to `Error`.
2. Change `NSURL` to `URL`
3. Change `!` to `?`

Using that you can write a method like this:

```
class func preloadImageWithUrlString(_ urlString: String, fetchedClosure: ImageFetchedClosure? = nil) {
    let imageURLString = addWidthParameter(urlString, width: width)
    guard let url = URL(string: imageURLString) else { 
        // Call closure with some error...
        fetchedClosure(nil, MyError.someCustomErrorHere, SDImageCacheTypeNone, true, nil)
        return
    }

    SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: url, options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), progress: nil) { 
        (maybeImage, maybeError, cacheType, finished, imageURL) in
        if let closure = completionClosure {
            closure(maybeImage, maybeError, cacheType, url)
        }
    }
}
```

That you use like this:

```
UIImageView.preloadImageWithUrlString("http://some.url.com/myImage.png") { 
    (maybeImage, maybeError, cacheType, finished, imageURL) in
    print("prefetching done")
}
```

Comment: Did you change from `NSError` to `Error` as well? I will update my answer to make that clear

Comment: Thanks, in my case it is working after changing UIImage! to UIImage? and NSError! to Error?, thanks a lot .

Comment: @Sajjon - how would one know this? Given that the method signature is in Obj-C but it seems you put the Swift-translated method signature up there. How did you get that?